# The CnosDB documentation does not match the actual behavior

Tags: cnosdb

doc link:
[enter link description here](https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/latest/manage/tenant.html#grant-admin-permission)

Doc Examples：

```
 create user dev;
 alter user dev set granted_admin = true;
```

Test:

```
    public ❯ alter user User9 set granted_admin = true;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"030008","error_message":"The user user9 not found"}

Stack backtrace:
   0: anyhow::error::<impl anyhow::Error>::msg
   1: anyhow::__private::format_err
   2: client::ctx::SessionContext::sql::{{closure}}
   3: client::exec::exec_and_print::{{closure}}
   4: client::exec::exec_from_repl::{{closure}}
   5: cnosdb_cli::main::{{closure}}
   6: cnosdb_cli::main
   7: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace
   8: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}
   9: core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce<A> for &F>::call_once
             at ./rustc/696aaad58c57a589f6fb2ecff5bae2eec581cb71/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:287:13
  10: std::panicking::try::do_call
             at ./rustc/696aaad58c57a589f6fb2ecff5bae2eec581cb71/library/std/src/panicking.rs:485:40
  11: std::panicking::try
             at ./rustc/696aaad58c57a589f6fb2ecff5bae2eec581cb71/library/std/src/panicking.rs:449:19
  12: std::panic::catch_unwind
             at ./rustc/696aaad58c57a589f6fb2ecff5bae2eec581cb71/library/std/src/panic.rs:140:14
  13: std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}
             at ./rustc/696aaad58c57a589f6fb2ecff5bae2eec581cb71/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:48
  14: std::panicking::try::do_call
             at ./rustc/696aaad58c57a589f6fb2ecff5bae2eec581cb71/library/std/src/panicking.rs:485:40
  15: std::panicking::try
             at ./rustc/696aaad58c57a589f6fb2ecff5bae2eec581cb71/library/std/src/panicking.rs:449:19
  16: std::panic::catch_unwind
             at ./rustc/696aaad58c57a589f6fb2ecff5bae2eec581cb71/library/std/src/panic.rs:140:14
  17: std::rt::lang_start_internal
             at ./rustc/696aaad58c57a589f6fb2ecff5bae2eec581cb71/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:20
  18: main
  19: __libc_start_main
  20: _start
```

The results of my testing are inconsistent with the behavior described in the CnosDB documentation. Can you please explain the reason for this?